# How can I remove the unwanted part of sprite area

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite

How can we animate using this coin sprite image (suppose the background is not transparent, but white) http://blocksjs.com/demos/block/images/coin.png without getting the white parts? Suppose we want just the coin, not this white background, because, let's say, the background on canvas is black. How can we accomplish this?

Comment: You can't. There is nothing in the image data that says that certain parts of the image is background, so there is no automatic way to remove it. You need an image with the background color that you want, or with a transparent background.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. I guess the only way is to remove the background using an image editing program...

Comment: Your image background is transparent. The white background you are seeing is the default browser white. Inspect the image page, and add to the body `background: black;`.

Comment: true, I was asking more of a general case, using the link merely as an example. Edited to improve clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image provided is transparent so there's no need to eliminate the white background.  If you do have an image with a white background then you might try one of the globalCompositeOperations to draw only the dark pixels and ignore the white.

I've added a function to key out a color. You could key out the color of your image and save it before running the animation.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("can").getContext('2d');
var sprite = document.getElementById("sprite");
var sprite_width = 100;
var sprite_height = 100;
var sprite_frames = 10;
var sprite_frame = -1;
var sprite_x = 100;
var sprite_y = 0;
var sprite_fps = 10;
var sprite_time = 0;

var spriteCan = document.getElementById('spriteCan');
var sprites = [];

function makeSpriteCan() {
  var can = spriteCan;
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle="#FF00FF";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline='middle';
  ctx.font = "30pt Sans-serif";
  ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ctx.fillText(i, 50 + i * 100, 50);
  }
  
}

makeSpriteCan();
spriteCan = keyColor(spriteCan, 255,0,255);
sprites.push(spriteCan);
ani();


function spriteLoad() {
  sprites.unshift(sprite)
}


function ani() {
  var now_time = Date.now();
  if (now_time - sprite_time > 1000 / sprite_fps) {
    sprite_time = now_time;
    sprite_frame ++;
    sprite_frame %= sprite_frames;
  }
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  var frame_x = sprite_frame * sprite_width;
  var frame_y = 0;

  
  for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(sprites[i], frame_x, frame_y, sprite_width, sprite_height, sprite_x, sprite_y, sprite_width, sprite_height);
  }
  
  
  requestAnimationFrame(ani);
}


// key out a color in an image
function keyColor(img, r, g, b) {
  var can = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  can.width=img.width;
  can.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,can.width,can.height);
  var d = imageData.data;
  var length = d.length;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i+=4) {
     if (d[i] == r && d[i+1] == g && d[i+2] == b) {
         d[i+3] = 0;
     }; 
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  return can;
}
```

```css
#can {
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://blocksjs.com/demos/block/images/coin.png" id="sprite" onload="spriteLoad()"/>
<canvas id="spriteCan" width="1000" height="100"></canvas>
<canvas id="can" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Upvote for an answer that works nicely on this spritesheet. More generally, I worry a little bit if another sprite contains #FF00FF then that portion of the sprite will be made transparent also.